# Getting "NoneType object is not subscriptable" when creating fasta file

Tags: python, loops, nonetype, fasta

I am trying to create a multiple alignment fasta file from an user search of a gen and a sequence. To create this fasta file I am using the following:

```
for seq in fasta_result:
        ofile.write(">" + names[x] + "\n" + fasta_result[y] + "\n")
        x +=1
        y +=1
```

This is working fine as long as the name list is a simple list:

```
names = ['name_1','name_2','name_3','name_4']
```

It gives me a fasta file with the intended result. However, my intention is that instead of generic names like 'name_1', 'name_2', etc... I want to get the names of the genomes.

I have a function that does the job:

```
example = 'Rv0001'
genome = 'tuberculosis'
print(alignment_search(example, genome)
```

The result is a list:

```
['Rv0001', 'MSMEG_RS33460', 'MRA_RS00005', 'BQ2027_RS00005']
```

However, when I modify the first part of the code to have:

```
names = alignment_search(example, genome)
```

I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/pq/ghtv3wj159j681vy0ny3tz9w0000gp/T/ipykernel_34390/940860269.py in <module>
     18 genome = genome_location(before, after, alignment)
     19 
---> 20 filename = custom_fasta(genome, example, genome)
     21 
     22 aln = AlignIO.read('/Users/dissertation/Documents/Dissertation-real/cgi-mycoapollo/db/genomes/' + filename + '_out.fasta','fasta')

/var/folders/pq/ghtv3wj159j681vy0ny3tz9w0000gp/T/ipykernel_34390/573793128.py in custom_fasta(locations_dict, example, genome)
     55 
     56     for seq in fasta_result:
---> 57         for value in names:
     58             ofile.write(">" + names[x] + "\n" + fasta_result[y] + "\n")
     59 

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

I am not sure why it gives me this error, I have checked that the result of the function alignment_search(example, genome) is indeed a list type:

```
print(type(alignment_search(example, genome)))
<class 'list'>
```

So why is it working with a simple list but when it depends on the result of a function it gives the NoneType error?

Thanks!

Comment: And what is the type of `fasta_result`?

Comment: Perhaps you would like to post a [mre] that would make it possible for someone to identify the problem.

Comment: @BoarGules fasta_result is also a list

Comment: Insert a line after 56 to print the type/contents of `names` just before the error. I'm guessing `names` *at that point* isn't what you think.

Comment: I have modified the function I was creating and now I give the list directly without calling it inside the function again and that made it work. Thank you for the advices!